# How do you snap knife to vertices obstructed by faces?

Tags: snapping, knife-tool

[image]

I made this mesh by applying a boolean and now I want to cut parallel with the top of the hole.
[image]
The Loop Cut command won't snap to the point, so I'm trying to use the Knife tool and cut through the mesh but it won't snap to the point I want because there is a face obstructing it from the view. How can I get the knife to snap to a point that isn't directly seen by the current view?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it with the *Knife* tool, why do you try to do it from the top or the side or whatever view that is? View the cube from the front with the hole facing you.

Enable the *Knife* tool with <kbd>K</kbd> and then <kbd>A</kbd> for *angle constraint* and <kbd>C</kbd> for *cut through* (you find the tool options in the bottom status bar). Now you can use the *Knife* to snap to one vertex of the hole and cut horizontally to the next edge, right-click for placing the next cut the same way on the other side and confirm the cuts with <kbd>Return</kbd>.

[image: first cut]

[image: second cut]

After confirming the cuts, you have a loop cut from the hole in the front to the back edges, only the face at the back is not cut:

[image: finished cuts]

To do this, select both the opposite vertices at the backside and press <kbd>J</kbd> ( do **not** use <kbd>F</kbd> which would create an unconnected edge):

[image: select vertices]

After that, the face at the back is split between the two vertices and you have a finished horizontal cut around the cube:

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

Why does *Loop Cut* not "snap to the point"? If you set *Snapping* to *Vertex* and either enable the *Snap* tool or hold the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key for temporary snapping, then the *Loop Cut* snaps to the vertex:

[image: snapping loop cut]

The only thing with this option is, the cut does not use the existing vertices at the top of the hole. But after creating the cut, you can enable the *Auto Merge* function together with the *Split Edges & Faces* option. Then select all vertices with <kbd>A</kbd> and move them exactly 0 meters (the *Auto Merge* needs a transform action to work but you do not really want to move the vertices) by pressing <kbd>G</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd> and left-click to confirm. Now the cut is merged with the vertices.

[image: auto merge function]